# Getting all possible combinations in every single possible order?

Tags: python, list, generator, combinations, python-itertools

stack overflow community! I am once again asking for your help...

I need to make a combination generator that gets all the possible combinations of a list.
BEFORE you tell me to use itertools let me tell you why it wouldn't work in my situation:

My code looks like this:

```
import itertools

a = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"+",
"-",
"*",
"**",
"("
")"
]

for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(a, L):
        print(subset)
```

The output is:

```
()
('1',)
('2',)
('3',)
('4',)
('5',)
('+',)
('-',)
('*',)
('**',)
('()',)
('1', '2')
('1', '3')
('1', '4')
('1', '5')
('1', '+')
('1', '-')
('1', '*')
('1', '**')
('1', '()')
('2', '3')
('2', '4')
('2', '5')
('2', '+')
('2', '-')
('2', '*')
('2', '**')
('2', '()')
('3', '4')
('3', '5')
('3', '+')
('3', '-')
('3', '*')
('3', '**')
('3', '()')
('4', '5')
('4', '+')
('4', '-')
('4', '*')
('4', '**')
('4', '()')
('5', '+')
('5', '-')
('5', '*')
('5', '**')
('5', '()')
('+', '-')
('+', '*')
('+', '**')
('+', '()')
('-', '*')
('-', '**')
('-', '()')
('*', '**')
('*', '()')
('**', '()')
('1', '2', '3')
('1', '2', '4')
('1', '2', '5')
('1', '2', '+')
('1', '2', '-')
('1', '2', '*')
('1', '2', '**')
('1', '2', '()')
('1', '3', '4')
('1', '3', '5')
('1', '3', '+')
('1', '3', '-')
('1', '3', '*')
('1', '3', '**')
('1', '3', '()')
('1', '4', '5')
('1', '4', '+')
('1', '4', '-')
('1', '4', '*')
('1', '4', '**')
('1', '4', '()')
('1', '5', '+')
('1', '5', '-')
('1', '5', '*')
('1', '5', '**')
('1', '5', '()')
('1', '+', '-')
('1', '+', '*')
('1', '+', '**')
('1', '+', '()')
('1', '-', '*')
('1', '-', '**')
('1', '-', '()')
('1', '*', '**')
('1', '*', '()')
('1', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4')
('2', '3', '5')
('2', '3', '+')
('2', '3', '-')
('2', '3', '*')
('2', '3', '**')
('2', '3', '()')
('2', '4', '5')
('2', '4', '+')
('2', '4', '-')
('2', '4', '*')
('2', '4', '**')
('2', '4', '()')
('2', '5', '+')
('2', '5', '-')
('2', '5', '*')
('2', '5', '**')
('2', '5', '()')
('2', '+', '-')
('2', '+', '*')
('2', '+', '**')
('2', '+', '()')
('2', '-', '*')
('2', '-', '**')
('2', '-', '()')
('2', '*', '**')
('2', '*', '()')
('2', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5')
('3', '4', '+')
('3', '4', '-')
('3', '4', '*')
('3', '4', '**')
('3', '4', '()')
('3', '5', '+')
('3', '5', '-')
('3', '5', '*')
('3', '5', '**')
('3', '5', '()')
('3', '+', '-')
('3', '+', '*')
('3', '+', '**')
('3', '+', '()')
('3', '-', '*')
('3', '-', '**')
('3', '-', '()')
('3', '*', '**')
('3', '*', '()')
('3', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+')
('4', '5', '-')
('4', '5', '*')
('4', '5', '**')
('4', '5', '()')
('4', '+', '-')
('4', '+', '*')
('4', '+', '**')
('4', '+', '()')
('4', '-', '*')
('4', '-', '**')
('4', '-', '()')
('4', '*', '**')
('4', '*', '()')
('4', '**', '()')
('5', '+', '-')
('5', '+', '*')
('5', '+', '**')
('5', '+', '()')
('5', '-', '*')
('5', '-', '**')
('5', '-', '()')
('5', '*', '**')
('5', '*', '()')
('5', '**', '()')
('+', '-', '*')
('+', '-', '**')
('+', '-', '()')
('+', '*', '**')
('+', '*', '()')
('+', '**', '()')
('-', '*', '**')
('-', '*', '()')
('-', '**', '()')
('*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4')
('1', '2', '3', '5')
('1', '2', '3', '+')
('1', '2', '3', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5')
('1', '2', '4', '+')
('1', '2', '4', '-')
('1', '2', '4', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+')
('1', '2', '5', '-')
('1', '2', '5', '*')
('1', '2', '5', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5')
('1', '3', '4', '+')
('1', '3', '4', '-')
('1', '3', '4', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+')
('1', '3', '5', '-')
('1', '3', '5', '*')
('1', '3', '5', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '-')
('1', '3', '+', '*')
('1', '3', '+', '**')
('1', '3', '+', '()')
('1', '3', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+')
('1', '4', '5', '-')
('1', '4', '5', '*')
('1', '4', '5', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '-')
('1', '4', '+', '*')
('1', '4', '+', '**')
('1', '4', '+', '()')
('1', '4', '-', '*')
('1', '4', '-', '**')
('1', '4', '-', '()')
('1', '4', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5')
('2', '3', '4', '+')
('2', '3', '4', '-')
('2', '3', '4', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+')
('2', '3', '5', '-')
('2', '3', '5', '*')
('2', '3', '5', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '-')
('2', '3', '+', '*')
('2', '3', '+', '**')
('2', '3', '+', '()')
('2', '3', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+')
('2', '4', '5', '-')
('2', '4', '5', '*')
('2', '4', '5', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '-')
('2', '4', '+', '*')
('2', '4', '+', '**')
('2', '4', '+', '()')
('2', '4', '-', '*')
('2', '4', '-', '**')
('2', '4', '-', '()')
('2', '4', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '-')
('2', '5', '+', '*')
('2', '5', '+', '**')
('2', '5', '+', '()')
('2', '5', '-', '*')
('2', '5', '-', '**')
('2', '5', '-', '()')
('2', '5', '*', '**')
('2', '5', '*', '()')
('2', '5', '**', '()')
('2', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+')
('3', '4', '5', '-')
('3', '4', '5', '*')
('3', '4', '5', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '-')
('3', '4', '+', '*')
('3', '4', '+', '**')
('3', '4', '+', '()')
('3', '4', '-', '*')
('3', '4', '-', '**')
('3', '4', '-', '()')
('3', '4', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '-')
('3', '5', '+', '*')
('3', '5', '+', '**')
('3', '5', '+', '()')
('3', '5', '-', '*')
('3', '5', '-', '**')
('3', '5', '-', '()')
('3', '5', '*', '**')
('3', '5', '*', '()')
('3', '5', '**', '()')
('3', '+', '-', '*')
('3', '+', '-', '**')
('3', '+', '-', '()')
('3', '+', '*', '**')
('3', '+', '*', '()')
('3', '+', '**', '()')
('3', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '-')
('4', '5', '+', '*')
('4', '5', '+', '**')
('4', '5', '+', '()')
('4', '5', '-', '*')
('4', '5', '-', '**')
('4', '5', '-', '()')
('4', '5', '*', '**')
('4', '5', '*', '()')
('4', '5', '**', '()')
('4', '+', '-', '*')
('4', '+', '-', '**')
('4', '+', '-', '()')
('4', '+', '*', '**')
('4', '+', '*', '()')
('4', '+', '**', '()')
('4', '-', '*', '**')
('4', '-', '*', '()')
('4', '-', '**', '()')
('4', '*', '**', '()')
('5', '+', '-', '*')
('5', '+', '-', '**')
('5', '+', '-', '()')
('5', '+', '*', '**')
('5', '+', '*', '()')
('5', '+', '**', '()')
('5', '-', '*', '**')
('5', '-', '*', '()')
('5', '-', '**', '()')
('5', '*', '**', '()')
('+', '-', '*', '**')
('+', '-', '*', '()')
('+', '-', '**', '()')
('+', '*', '**', '()')
('-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '*')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('3', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '+', '-', '*', '**', '()')
```

There are two problems with this...

The first and smallest problem...
The output is in tuples.

Second and largest...
This only gives the combinations of the different characters that is in a tuple at once, but i need it to also every possible order of the characters.

Regards Mike.

Comment: Have you considered `itertools.permutations` instead of combinations? `map(list, itertools.permutations(a, L))`

Comment: @Mark_M How does that work?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you need all combinations, or permutations of the list?

Comment: @Xinthral i think i need just permutations

Comment: @Miklath This may help illustrate things on [G4G](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/). The topic can get complex quickly, but to print all orderings of the full list (which is what I think you're getting at) then that page should work. If not, maybe putting a sample of what you want the output to contain then I can take another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using permutations instead of combinations

```
import itertools

a = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"+",
"-",
"*",
"**",
"("
")"
]

for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(a, L):
        print(list(subset))
```

Updated to save all permutations to a string

```
string = ""

for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(a, L):
        string += "("
        string += ''.join([str(elem) for elem in subset])
        print(''.join([str(elem) for elem in subset]))
        string += ")+"

print(string)
```

Comment: YAY this works, but what about the tuple part

Comment: I would like it all connected in a string

Comment: like so "(1)+23-*"

Comment: Not sure if I've understood what you want but maybe you can work with the second piece of code I've added to create your string?

Comment: perfect... but is there a way to remove the spaces?

Comment: Yep, I've removed it by changing ' '.join to ''.join above.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
from itertools import permutations

b = []
for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
    b += list(map(list, permutations(a, i)))
```

b is now the list you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the whole thing as an iterator using a two level comprehension and convert tuples to lists in the process.

```
from itertools import permutations
subsets = (list(p) for s in range(len(a)) for p in permutations(a,s+1))
for subset in subsets:print(subset)
```

output:

```
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['+']
['-']
['*']
['**']
['()']
['1', '2']
['1', '3']
['1', '4']
['1', '5']
...
```